# Embed nested, filtered collection field type in event subscriber

Tags: forms, symfony

I am creating a dynamic question/ answer form. I need to display a collection of answer fields for a given section that pertain only to the logged-in user.  The data model is:

Section has many SectionQuestion (a section represents a page of the form)
SectionQuestion has one Question and many Answer
Answer has one User and one SectionQuestion

My form code is:

```
//SectionFormType.php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('sectionQuestions', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new SectionQuestionFormType($this->answerListener),
            'label' => false
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}

//SectionQuestionFormType.php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventSubscriber($this->answerListener);
}

//AnswerListener.php
public function preSetData($event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (null === $data) {
        return;
    }

    $form->add(
        'answers',
        'collection',
        array(
            'type' => new AnswerFormType($data->getQuestion()),
            'auto_initialize' => false,
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false,
        )
    );
}

//AnswerFormType.php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $fieldType = $this->question->getAnswerType();

    $config = array(
        'required' => true,
        'label'    => $this->question->getText(),
        'auto_initialize' => false
    );

    if ($fieldType == 'choice') {
        $valueList = $this->question->getValueList();
        $values = $valueList->loadChoiceList();

        $config['choice_list'] = $values;
        $config['empty_value'] = 'Please select one';
    }

    $builder->add('answer', $fieldType, $config);
}
```

This code is functional, but not what I really need.  I need the collection added in AnswerListener to provide a mixture of existing answers that relate to the currently logged in user *and* blank answers where no answer has been entered yet.

1. I know that instead of naming the collection field in AnswerListener 'answers' (which matches the relationship property in SectionQuestions) I can name it, say, 'filteredAnswers' and write a getter/setter in SectionQuestions entity class that returns a subset of the answers. But! I can't access the logged-in user inside the getter in the Entity class.
2. I can't change the field type to Entity either because, as far as I know, I won't be able to stipulate that the AnswerFormType form is used, which is crucial as it sets the answer field label with a value from my Question entity (the actual question text).
3. Inside AnswerListener, I could use $form->add($this->factory->createNamed(....)) and provide a subset of data this way (as I could access the entity manager logged-in user inside the AnswerListener class and perform a query). But! I can't figure out how to make this a collection field type. I can get the form to display properly using createNamed like this:

   ```
   $form->add(
       $this->factory->createNamed(
           'answer', 
           new AnswerFormType(
               $data->getQuestion()), 
               $answer, 
               array(
                       'auto_initialize' => false,
                       'mapped' => false,
                       'label' => false
                )
           )
       )
   )
   ```

...But! This only adds individual answer fields to the form, so values posted never get persisted to the database (presumably because SectionQuestions wants them to be added via the 'answers' property which isn't reached).

Seems I'm stumped at every turn.  Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Comment: I'm going to TRY to solve this by creating a form type extension for the collection form type. I have no idea if this is a rabbit hole or not.  Any and all other ideas welcome!

Comment: Actually, now I'm relooking at my data model.  Maybe I don't need to embed a collection of Answer in SectionQuestion at all.  I'm now looking at a completely different way of generating the answer form for each question in a section.  Will post the result if it works out.  As long as an answer knows which user it belongs to, and which SectionQuestion it's an answer for, that's all I need.  A user needs to know all of it's anwers but a SectionQuestion doesn't necessarily need to know all of it's answers... Might be onto something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured this out myself.  I had to embed individual 'answer' forms as described in point 3 above.  As mentioned though, SectionQuestions relates to Answer via an $answers property which expects to be a collection, so I couldn't save the form.  To get around this, I used the 'mapped' => false option in createNamed and accessed the form data as an array.  Easier to see in code, so here it is:

```
//AnswerListener.php
public function preSetData($event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (null === $data) {
        return;
    }

    $answerRepository = $this->entityManager
                             ->getRepository('RecruitmentCoreBundle:Answer');

    $answer = $answerRepository->findOneBy(
        array(
            'sectionQuestion_id' => $data->getId(),
            'user_id' => $authenticated_user_id
        )
    );

    if(!$answer) {
     $answer = null;
    }

    $form->add(
        $this->factory->createNamed(
            'answer',
            new AnswerFormType($data->getQuestion()),
            $answer,
            $formOptions = array (
                'auto_initialize' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => false,

            )
        )
    );
}
```

You can see here that I check the database to see whether the logged-in user has already provided an answer for the given SectionQuestion.  If they have, that is passed to createdNamed, if not, null is passed and a blank answer form field is displayed onscreen.

To save the form, I have a service that looks like this:

```
//FormService.php
class FormService
{
    private $formFactory;
    private $entityManager;
    private $sectionForm;

    /**
     * @param FormFactoryInterface $factory
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param SectionFormType $form
     */
    public function __construct(
         FormFactoryInterface $factory, 
         EntityManager $em, 
         SectionFormType $form)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $factory;
        $this->entityManager = $em;
        $this->sectionForm = $form;
    }

    public function generateSectionForm($roundId, $sectionId)
    {

        $sectionRepository = $this->entityManager
                                  ->getRepository('RecruitmentCoreBundle:Section');

        $section = $sectionRepository->findOneBy(array('id' => $sectionId));

        return $this->formFactory->create($this->sectionForm, $section);
    }


    public function saveSectionAnswers($form, Section $section)
    {
        foreach($form['sectionQuestions'] as $sectionQuestion) {

            $answer = $sectionQuestion['answer']->getData();

            if (null === $answer->getId()) {
                $sectionQuestion = $sectionQuestion->getData();
                $answer->setSectionQuestion($sectionQuestion);
                $answer->setUser(//logged in user);
            }

            $this->entityManager->persist($answer);
        }

        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Even though I used 'mapped' => false in the createNamed method call in AnswerListener.php, you can see in the saveSectionAnswers method of my FormService class that $sectionQuestion['answer']->getData(); returns an Answer object.  This is populated with the submitted form data for the given SectionQuestion which I can then persist to the database.  Presumably the Answer object is provided because I define the Answer entity as the data_class in my AnswerFormType.php class:

```
//AnswerFormType.php
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
         array(
        'data_class' => 'Recruitment\CoreBundle\Entity\Answer'
         )
    );
}
```

Anyway, it works and provides exactly the functionality I needed.